# How to translate a date in Angular

Tags: angular, date, translate

I'm using ng-translate to translate my app. But I'm stuck on translating a string date :

- If it's in french, I would see `'Le 24 décembre à 13h'`
- If it's in english, I would see `'December 24th at 1pm'`

How can I do such a thing ?
I also have to translate it in german

Comment: you can look at moment.js with the different formats avaliable and use french locale https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install momentjs:

```
npm install moment --save
import * as moment from 'moment';
```

Next use Moment Multiple Locale Support:

```
moment().format('LL');
```

HINT: According to your locale, you have a better format:

```
moment().format('ll');   // 4 avr. 2018 for french locale <br>
moment().format('LL');   // April 4, 2018 for US English <br>
```

Hope I help!

Comment: Seems to be what I was looking for. Thanks, I'll try it later but I'm certain that it will solve my issue